# Knowing a pixel value after making an RGBtoHSV conversion OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

Im trying to get the H,S and V Values of an image, so i convert an RGB image to HSV, and then just ask for the desired values, and then print them.. Im not quite sure im making this right, because when printing the Value (V of hsV) i get values of 100+ and i understand that the V just goes to 0-100, maybe im not using a correct method, here's the code:

```
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i=0,total=0;
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
IplImage* hsv;
CvSize size;
int key = 0, depth;


size = cvGetSize(img);
depth = img->depth;
hsv = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 3);

cvCvtColor( img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );   

for(i=0;i<480;i++){   //asking for the values in \ form (1,1)(2,2),...(480,480)     
    CvScalar s;

    s = cvGet2D(hsv,i,i);               
    printf("s=%f\n,s.val[2]);  //s.val[2] equals to hs**V** right?
 }
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvReleaseImage(&val);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer here is correct but here is a code snippet that I have to calculate the V channel in opencv.  I get the value from the Gimp app and this function gives me the opencv value.

```
//Max values: App HSV H=360 S=100 V=100 OpenCV H=180 S=255 V=255
double newHSV(double value)
{
    //new_val = value * opencv_max_range / other_app_max_range
    double newValue = value * 255 / 100;
    return newValue;
}
```

To check your opencv HSV values in another application like Gimp, just calculate the formula to:

```
gimp_value = opencv_value * other_app_max_range / opencv_max_range
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is correct. Just that values are a little different.

H should ideally go from 0-360. But because a byte can only hold 0-255, H values are halved. So the range is 0-180.

V and S use the full range of 0-255 to specify value and saturation.

You can read more about it here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cvtcolor